# Change opacity of thumbnail with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, hover, jquery-hover

I'm building a video gallery for a friend and I'm trying to change the thumbnail opacity on hover with jQuery fade.

I can change it with CSS, but I'm trying to get a fade with jQuery

Any tips on where I'm going wrong appreciated

Everything so far is in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MF3ZJ/71/).

I think the main problem is the jQuery code:

```
$(".thumbnail-element").hover(function () {
$(this).find('.thumb1').fadeIn(100);
},
function () {
$(this).find('.thumb1').fadeOut(100);    
});
```

Comment: can i ask why you want to change the opacity via jQuery instead of css?

Comment: well to have a fade rather than just changing opacity from a to b

Comment: are you trying to from b/w to color?

Comment: yeh from bw to colour, ive got it fade in but not out

Comment: @JamesKirkby As this is just a visual nicety and not core functionality I'd be extremely tempted to do this with CSS3 transitions (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) and not jQuery. The transitions will preform better than doing this in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution im looking for

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".thumb1").hover(
            function() {
                $(this).find('.adaptive-image').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 200);
                }, 
                function() {
                    $(this).find('.adaptive-image').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
            }
        );
    });
```

Comment: you can still do it your way just flip the fadeIn and fadeOut and then target the img not the a tag